# Открыть файл по абсолютному пути в Django

Tags: python, django

Не понимаю почему я не могу открыть файл по абсолютному пути в django:

```
with open('/home/user/file.txt') as file:
```

Получаю ошибку, что такого файла нет. Однако файл точно есть, т.к. он открывается на сервере вот такой командой, например

```
vim /home/user/file.txt
```

Права на чтения нужному юзеру тоже выданы. В чем может быть дело?

Comment: Как Django запускаете?

Comment: @andreymal Ну, как обычно. `python manage.py runserver`

Comment: Для продакшена это вопиюще неправильно, но сейчас не об этом. А чуть конкретнее, где как чем этот `python manage.py runserver` запускаете?

Comment: @andreymal да не, это не продакшн) Это локально на убунте. Думаю, я разобрался, проблема была все-так в том, что файла дейстительно не было там, где он должне быть :)